# iOS swift - how to 'jump' only when landed, no mid air jumping - (touchesBegan)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a 2D game, the aim of the game is to jump over obstacles on the ground and flying in the air.  At present the character can jump multiple times in mid air and has the ability to fly.

I'm looking to only let the character jump every second or so, is there a way to set a time delay on 'touchesBegan'.  Ideally id like to be able to alter the time delay to ensure gameplay is fun yet challenging.

Below is a copy of my touchesBegan, let me know if you need more script or the below isn't quite right.

Thank you.

```
override func  touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    cat.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    cat.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 20))
}
```

Comment: For the time delay: when the character jumps, set a flag disallowing jumps, start a timer when you jump, have the action of the timer remove the flag when the timer expires. (Personally I think such a delay is likely to be terrible gameplay no matter how short; rather detect when the character is on the ground and always allow jumps there.)

Answer (score 0):

```
let runningBar = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "ground")
var velocityY = CGFloat(0)
var onGround = true

func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    initHero()

}

func initHero() {
    hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "hero")

    self.heroBaseline = self.runningBar.position.y + (self.runningBar.size.height / 2) +
        (self.hero.size.height / 2)
    self.hero.position = CGPointMake(
        CGRectGetMinX(self.frame) + (self.hero.size.width / 3) + (self.hero.size.width / 4),
        self.heroBaseline)
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if self.onGround {
        self.velocityY = -18.0
        self.onGround = false
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if self.velocityY < -9.0 {
        self.velocityY = -9.0
    }
}
```

You need to create a baseline (ground) and limit it to that like in the code above.